# how to include both columns in where clause for searching

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to search my data from either of two table columns but the following code is not working what can I do ???

```
Cursor c = queryBuilder.query(ourHelper.getReadableDatabase(),                  
new String[] { "_ID", SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2, SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID }, KEY_ADDRESS + " like ? " + " OR " + KEY_ROWID + " like ? ", selectionArgs, null, null, KEY_ADDRESS + " asc ", "10");
```

Comment: Is it an error, or is it returning empty?

Comment: not an error but searches only from the KEY_ADDRESS column

Comment: Hmm well I don't see anything wrong with the code above, maybe its the contents of selectionArgs

Answer (score 0):

Bro, it is easy .... I hope it will work for your where clause

```
String where = KEY_ADDRESS  + "=" + variable + " and " + KEY_ROWID  + "='" + var_id + "'";
Cursor c = mDb.query(true, TABLE_MENUS, new String[] { your column name}, where, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: not working bro and what if the variable is not fixed.