# How to concat string and table column?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I'm concatenate two columns as shown below

```
String col2 = KEY_ENGLISH + " || ' ' || '-' || ' ' || " + KEY_NEPALI;
```

which gives output as

KEY_ENGLISH - KEY_NEPALI

But I need to display as

[KEY_ENGLISH][KEY_NEPALI]

Using

```
String col2 = " || '[' || " + KEY_ENGLISH + " || ']' || " + " || '[' || " + KEY_NEPALI + " || ']' || ";
```

I'm not getting desired output. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`||` is a concatenation operator. What your string will contain is this;

```
 || '[' || KEY_ENGLISH || ']' ||  || '[' || KEY_NEPALI || ']' ||
```

...which has a lot of extraneous operators.

What you want is instead just `||` between your strings as in;

```
 '[' || KEY_ENGLISH || '][' || KEY_NEPALI || ']'
```

...which would be written as;

```
String col2 = "'[' || " + KEY_ENGLISH + " || '][' || " + KEY_NEPALI + " || ']'";
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you answer this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539530/how-to-include-both-columns-in-where-clause-for-searching